# Longtable with multicolumn header and linebreak issues in multirow

Tags: longtable, multirow, multicolumn

I would like to create this table:

[image]

The code for this is in the second table. (Thanks to Bernard for this!)
Unfortunately I get two errors because of these two tables.

The first one is: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \end{tabularx}

The second one is: Misplaced \omit. \end{tabularx}

The Code is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularx, multirow, caption, makecell, hhline}      
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{ltablex}

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
TABLE 1
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\setlist[itemize]{wide=0pt, labelsep=2pt, leftmargin=*, nosep, before 
=\mbox{}\vspace*{-.7\baselineskip}, after=\vspace*{-.8\baselineskip}}
\caption{\label{tab:Gestaltungsbereiche}Gestaltungsbereiche}
%
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|*{3}{>{\RaggedRight}X|}}
\hhline{~|---|}
\multicolumn{1}{r|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}
{\cellcolor{Gainsboro}Gestaltungsbereiche} \\
\hhline{~|---|}
\rowcolor{Gainsboro} \multicolumn{1}{r|}{\cellcolor{white}} &% 
\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}X}{\centering Betriebsmittel\newline \centering 
(B)}
\makecell{Betriebsmittel\\ (B)} & \makecell{Organisation\\ (O)} & 
\makecell{Raum- und \\Gebäudetechnik \\ (R)}\\
\hline
\multirow{11}{*}[-1ex]{\rotatebox{90}{Fabrikobjekte}}
& \begin{itemize}
    \item Fertigungseinrichtungen
    \item Montageeinrichtungen
    \item Logistikeinrichtungen
    \item Qualitätseinrichtungen
    \item Informations- und 
    \newline Kommunikations\-einrichtungen
    \item Ver- und Entsorgungs\-einrichtungen
    \item Übergeordnete Systeme
    \item Mobiliar
\end{itemize} %
& \begin{itemize}
    \item Unternehmensstrategie
    \item Logistikkonzept
    \item Prozessgestaltung
    \item Aufbauorganisations\-gestaltung
    \item Arbeitsorganisation
    \item Qualitätssicherungs\-konzept
\end{itemize} %
& \begin{itemize}
    \item Grundstück
    \item Bau\-konstruktion
    \item Technische Anlagen
    \item Außenanlagen
    \item Ausstattung
    \item Konzepte
\end{itemize} \\%
\hline
\end{tabularx}%
\end{table}%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
TABLE 2
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newpage
\keepXColumns
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|*{2}{>{\RaggedRight}X|}p{9cm}|}
\caption{Betriebsmittel: Fabrikobjekte}
\label{tab:addlabel}%\\
\hhline{~|---|}
\rowcolor{Gainsboro} \multicolumn{1}{r|}{\cellcolor{white}}&
\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\columncolor{Gainsboro}[\tabcolsep][1em]}X}
{\centering Fabrikobjekte 1.Ordnung}&
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{Fabrikobjekte 2.Ordnung}
\\
\hhline{----}
\endfirsthead
\hhline{~|---|}
\rowcolor{Gainsboro} \multicolumn{1}{r|}{\cellcolor{white}}&
\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\columncolor{Gainsboro}[\tabcolsep][1em]}X}
{\centering Fabrikobjekte 1.Ordnung}&
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{Fabrikobjekte 2.Ordnung}
 \\
\hhline{----}
\endhead
\multirow{45}{*}[-1ex]{\rotatebox{90}{Gestaltungsfeld: Betriebsmittel}}  
%%%
& \multirow{11}{*}{Fertigungseinrichtung} & \multirow{5}{*}{Maschine} &
Gestell \\
& & & Antriebe\\
& & & Kinematisches System \\
& & & Steuerungs-/ Mess-/Regel- \&
Diagnosesysteme \\
& & & Hilfssysteme / Peripherie \\[0.4ex]
\cline{3-4}
& &
\multirow{3}{*}{Vorrichtung / Hilfmittel} &
Vorrichtungs- \& Spannsysteme \\
& & & Werkstückflusssystem \\
& & & Steuerung \\[0.4ex]
\cline{3-4}& & Werkzeuge & \\[0.4ex]
\cline{2-4}& \multirow{9}{*}{Montageeinrichtungen} & {\multirow{5}{*}
{Montagegrundplatz}} & {Gestell} \\
& & & Antriebe\\
& & & Kinematisches System \\
& & & Steuerungs-/ Mess-/Regel- \& Diagnosesysteme \\
& & & Hilfssysteme / Peripherie \\[0.4ex]
\cline{3-4}
& & \multirow{3}{*}{Vorrichtung / Hilfmittel} & {Vorrichtungs- \& 
Spannsysteme} \\
& & &{Werkstückflusssystem} \\
& & & {Steuerung} \\[0.4ex]
\cline{3-4}& & {Werkzeuge} &  \\[0.4ex]
\cline{2-4}& \multirow{25}{*}{Logistikeinrichtungen} & {\multirow{6}{*}
{Transporteinrichtungen}} & {Gestell} \\
& & & Transportvorrichtung\\
& & & Antriebe\\
& & & Kinematisches System \\
& & & Steuerung \\
& & & Hilfssysteme / Peripherie \\[0.4ex]
\cline{3-4}
& & {\multirow{6}{*}{Handhabungseinrichtungen}} & {Gestell} \\
& & & Handhabungsvorrichtung\\
& & & Antriebe\\
& & & Kinematisches System \\
& & & Steuerung \\
& & & Hilfssysteme / Peripherie \\[0.4ex]
\cline{3-4}

\end{tabularx}%
\end{document}
```

I appreciate every comment.

My current result for the second table is this:

[image]

Comment: please make your example so that people can run it and see the problem. But longtable does not have a `[!htbp]` argument, the `\centering` inside longtable can not work and will stop `\caption` working at all, you have not specified any columns for the longtable, there should be an argument such as `{ccc}`

Comment: Presumably you get tex errors from this input (once it is made into a document) if you get errors it is best to ask about the error and show the full error message (the output pdf after an error is not intended to be reasonable, tex just recovers enough to syntax check the rest of the document)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Now it should be possible to run this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\centering` isn't needed for a `longtable`: it's automatically centred by default. You don't have to insert a tabularx environment in a longtable to say it will spread obver pages. You simply have to load a package which adds the functionality (and the syntax) of `longtable` to `tabularx`.  I suggest to use `ltablex`.

The syntax is that of longtable: you put the \caption *inside* tabularx, before the declaration for the `first table head` (these declarations end with `\endfirsthead).

Then I suggest to add the column heads with the declarations for heads of the following heads (which end with `\endhead`).

I removed all the `\multicolumn{1}{l|}` in the last column, which prevent line breaking and generate overflowing into the margin.

So here is the code I propose:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{multirow, caption, makecell, hhline}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\keepXColumns
\begin{document}
%\begin{longtable}
%\centering
%\caption{Betriebsmittel: Fabrikobjekte}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|*{3}{>{\RaggedRight}X|}}
\caption{Betriebsmittel: Fabrikobjekte}
  \label{tab:addlabel}%\\
    \hhline{~|---|}
     \rowcolor{Gainsboro} \multicolumn{1}{r|}{\cellcolor{white}}&
    \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\columncolor{Gainsboro}[\tabcolsep][1em]}X}{\centering Fabrikobjekte 1.Ordnung}&
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Fabrikobjekte 2.Ordnung}
    \\
    \hhline{----}
\endfirsthead
    \hhline{~|---|}
     \rowcolor{Gainsboro} \multicolumn{1}{r|}{\cellcolor{white}}&
    \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\columncolor{Gainsboro}[\tabcolsep][1em]}X}{\centering Fabrikobjekte 1.Ordnung}&
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Fabrikobjekte 2.Ordnung}
    \\
    \hhline{----}
\endhead
    \multirow{12}{*}[-1ex]{\rotatebox{90}{Gestaltungsfeld: Betriebsmittel}}
     %%%

     & \multirow{11}{*}{Fertigungseinrichtung} & \multirow{5}{*}{Maschine} &
     Gestell \\
     & & & Antriebe\\
     & & & Kinematisches System \\
     & & & Steuerungs-/ Mess-/Regel- \&
     Diagnosesysteme \\
     & & & Hilfssysteme / Peripherie \\[0.4ex]
     \cline{3-4}
     & &
     \multirow{3}[2]{*}{Vorrichtung / Hilfmittel} &
     Vorrichtungs- \& Spannsysteme \\
     & & & Werkstückflusssystem \\
     & & & Steuerung \\[0.4ex]
     \cline{3-4}& & Werkzeuge & \\[0.4ex]
     \cline{2-4}\\
     %%%
    \end{tabularx}%

    \end{document}
```

[image]

*Added* :

This code compiles fine with three tables. Note the third table is a shorter code to obtain the second table. I had change the number used in `multirow`: you must take the total number of *lines* in the rows the multirow cell must spread over, and not the number of *rows*, and possibly add a corrective optional argument for the vertical placement of the content.

On the other hand loading `ltablex` makes all `tabularx` environments a `longtable`. Here they are centred, do not float (do not nest them in `table`) and the caption must be inserted *inside* the environment.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{multirow, caption, makecell, hhline}
\usepackage{ltablex}%{tabularx}%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand\mypar{ \par\hangindent=1.5em\hangafter=1}

\begin{document}

\sffamily\captionsetup{font=sf}

\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\setlist[itemize]{wide=0pt, labelsep=2pt, leftmargin=*, nosep, before
  =\mbox{}\vspace*{-.7\baselineskip}, after=\vspace*{-.8\baselineskip}}
\keepXColumns
%
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|*{3}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X|}}
  \caption{\label{tab:Gestaltungsbereiche}Gestaltungsbereiche} \\
  \hhline{~|---|}
  \multicolumn{1}{r|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}
  {\cellcolor{Gainsboro}Gestaltungsbereiche} \\
  \hhline{~|---|}
  \rowcolor{Gainsboro} \multicolumn{1}{r|}{\cellcolor{white}} & %
  \makecell{Betriebsmittel \\ (B)} & \makecell{Organisation\\ (O)} &
  \makecell{Raum- und \\Gebäudetechnik \\ (R)}\\
  \hline
  \endfirsthead
  \multirow{11}{*}[-1ex]{\,\rotatebox{90}{Fabrikobjekte}\,}
                                                              &
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Fertigungseinrichtungen
    \item Montageeinrichtungen
    \item Logistikeinrichtungen
    \item Qualitätseinrichtungen
    \item Informations- und
          Kommunikations\-einrichtungen
    \item Ver- und Entsorgungs\-einrichtungen
    \item Übergeordnete Systeme
    \item Mobiliar
  \end{itemize} %
                                                              & \begin{itemize}
    \item Unternehmensstrategie
    \item Logistikkonzept
    \item Prozessgestaltung
    \item Aufbauorganisations\-gestaltung
    \item Arbeitsorganisation
    \item Qualitätssicherungs\-konzept
  \end{itemize} %
                                                              & \begin{itemize}
    \item Grundstück
    \item Bau\-konstruktion
    \item Technische Anlagen
    \item Außenanlagen
    \item Ausstattung
    \item Konzepte
  \end{itemize}
  \\%
  \hline
\end{tabularx}%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% TABLE 2
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newpage
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|*{2}{>{\RaggedRight}X|}>{\RaggedRight}p{4.8cm}|}
  \caption{Betriebsmittel: Fabrikobjekte}
  \label{tab:addlabel} \\
  \hhline{~|---|}
  \multicolumn{1}{r|}{\cellcolor{white}} &
  \cellcolor{Gainsboro}\centering Fabrikobjekte 1.Ordnung &
  \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor{Gainsboro}Fabrikobjekte 2.Ordnung}
  \\
  \hhline{----}
  \endfirsthead
  \hhline{~|---|}
  \rowcolor{Gainsboro} \multicolumn{1}{r|}{\cellcolor{white}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\columncolor{Gainsboro}[\tabcolsep][1em]}X}
  {\centering Fabrikobjekte 1.Ordnung} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Fabrikobjekte 2.Ordnung}
  \\
  \hhline{----}
  \endhead
  \hhline{----}
  \endfoot
  \multirow{32}{*}{\,\rotatebox{90}{Gestaltungsfeld: Betriebsmittel}\,}
  %
                                                              & \multirow{11}{=}{Fertigungseinrichtung} & \multirow{6}{*}{Maschine} &
  Gestell \\
                                                              & & & Antriebe \\
                                                              & & & Kinematisches System \\
                                                              & & & Steuerungs-/ Mess-/Regel- \& \par\quad Diagnosesysteme \\
                                                              & & & Hilfssysteme / Peripherie \\[0.4ex]
  \cline{3-4}
                                                              & &
  \multirow{3}{=}{Vorrichtung / Hilfmittel} &
  Vorrichtungs- \& Spannsysteme \\
                                                              & & & Werkstückflusssystem \\
                                                              & & & Steuerung \\[0.4ex]
  \cline{3-4} & & Werkzeuge & \\[0.4ex]
  \cline{2-4} & \multirow{11}{=}[-2pt]{Montageeinrichtungen} &
  \multirow{6}{=}{Montagegrundplatz} & Gestell \\
                                                              & & & Antriebe \\
                                                              & & & Kinematisches System \\
                                                              & & & Steuerungs-/ Mess-/Regel- \&\par\quad Diagnosesysteme \\
                                                              & & & Hilfssysteme / Peripherie \\[0.4ex]
  \cline{3-4}
                                                              & & \multirow{3}{=}{Vorrichtung / Hilfmittel} & {Vorrichtungs- \& Spannsysteme} \\
                                                              & & & Werkstückflusssystem \\
                                                              & & & Steuerung \\[0.4ex]
  \cline{3-4} & & {Werkzeuge} & \\[0.4ex]
  \cline{2-4} & \multirow{12}{=}{Logistikeinrichtungen} &
  \multirow{6}{=}{Transporteinrichtungen} & Gestell \\
                                                              & & & Transportvorrichtung \\
                                                              & & & Antriebe \\
                                                              & & & Kinematisches System \\
                                                              & & & Steuerung \\
                                                              & & & Hilfssysteme / Peripherie \\[0.4ex]
  \cline{3-4}
                                                              & & \multirow{6}{=}{Handhabungseinrichtungen} & Gestell \\
                                                              & & & Handhabungsvorrichtung \\
                                                              & & & Antriebe \\
                                                              & & & Kinematisches System \\
                                                              & & & Steuerung \\
                                                              & & & Hilfssysteme / Peripherie \\[0.4ex]
\end{tabularx}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% TABLE 2 bis
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newpage
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|*{2}{>{\RaggedRight}X|}>{\RaggedRight\everypar{\hangindent=1.5em\hangafter=1}}p{4.8cm}|}
  \caption{Betriebsmittel: Fabrikobjekte}
  \label{tab:addlabel} \\
  \hhline{~|---|}
  \multicolumn{1}{r|}{\cellcolor{white}} &
  \cellcolor{Gainsboro}\centering Fabrikobjekte 1.Ordnung &
  \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor{Gainsboro}Fabrikobjekte 2.Ordnung}
  \\
  \hhline{----}
  \endfirsthead
  \hhline{~|---|}
  \rowcolor{Gainsboro} \multicolumn{1}{r|}{\cellcolor{white}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\columncolor{Gainsboro}[\tabcolsep][1em]}X}
  {\centering Fabrikobjekte 1.Ordnung} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Fabrikobjekte 2.Ordnung}
  \\
  \hhline{----}
  \endhead
  \hhline{----}
  \endfoot
  \multirow{27}{*}{\,\rotatebox{90}{Gestaltungsfeld: Betriebsmittel}\,}
  %
                                                              & \multirow{11}{=}{Fertigungseinrichtung} & \multirow{6}{=}{Maschine}
                                                              & Gestell \par Antriebe \par Kinematisches System \par Steuerungs-/ Mess-/Regel- \& Diagnosesysteme \par Hilfssysteme / Peripherie \\[0.4ex]
  \cline{3-4}
                                                              & & \multirow{3}{=}{Vorrichtung / Hilfmittel} &
  Vorrichtungs- \& Spannsysteme \par Werkstückflusssystem \par Steuerung \\[0.4ex]
  \cline{3-4} & & Werkzeuge & \\[0.4ex]
  \cline{2-4} & \multirow{11}{=}[-2pt]{Montageeinrichtungen} & \multirow{6}{=}{Montagegrundplatz} %
                                                              & Gestell \par Antriebe \par Kinematisches System \par Steuerungs-/ Mess-/Regel- \& Diagnosesysteme \par Hilfssysteme / Peripherie \\[0.4ex]
  \cline{3-4}
                                                              & & \multirow{3}{=}{Vorrichtung / Hilfmittel} &
  Vorrichtungs- \& Spannsysteme \par Werkstückflusssystem \par Steuerung \\[0.4ex]
  \cline{3-4} & & {Werkzeuge} & \\[0.4ex]
  \cline{2-4} & \multirow{12}{=}{Logistikeinrichtungen} & \multirow{6}{*}{Transporteinrichtungen}
                                                              & Gestell \par Transportvorrichtung \par Antriebe \par Kinematisches System \par Steuerung \par Hilfssysteme / Peripherie \\[0.4ex]
  \cline{3-4}
                                                              & & \multirow{6}{=}{Handhabungseinrichtungen}
                                                              & Gestell \par Handhabungsvorrichtung \par Antriebe \par Kinematisches System \par Steuerung \par Hilfssysteme / Peripherie \\[0.4ex]
\end{tabularx}%

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for helping again. I posted an answer to my question with both tables you helped me with, because it creates an error if I use both tables together. Funnily enough it works if I just use one of them.

Comment: @Paul: I've corrected your code, and propose a new, simpler code for the second table. Please see if it's fine for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you get a TeX error you should not really look at the typeset result at all.

The error here is

```
! Package array Error:  Illegal pream-token (\centering): `c' used.
```

Because after the optional argument the first token is `\centering` when like most array environments, `longtable` is looking for a column specification.

The optional argument can only be `[c]`, `[l]` or `[r]` so `[!htbp]` is just ignored (no error is given for mostly historic reasons) so I've removed that optional argument.

so changing to

```
\begin{longtable}{ccc}
```

produces output with no error but the caption is to the left of the `tabularx` as you omitted the `\\` to end the `longtable` row.

I stop at this point as it isn't at all clear what you want. Currently the entire `longtable` table just has a single cell in a single column consisting of a nested `tabularx` if that is the real case you do not need `longtable` at all and could just have the `tabularx`  inside a `table` ?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{ragged2e} 
\usepackage{tabularx, multirow, caption, makecell, hhline}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{ccc}
\caption{Betriebsmittel: Fabrikobjekte}\\
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|*{3}{>{\RaggedRight}X|}}
\hhline{~|---|}
\rowcolor{Gainsboro} \multicolumn{1}{r|}{\cellcolor{white}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}X}{\centering Fabrikobjekte 1.Ordnung}&
\multicolumn{2}{>{\centering}X}{\centering Fabrikobjekte 2.Ordnung}
\\
\hline
\multirow{11}{*}[-1ex]{\rotatebox{90}{Gestaltungsfeld: Betriebsmittel}}
 %%%

 & \multirow{9}{*}{Fertigungseinrichtung} & \multirow{5}{*}{Maschine} & 
 \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Gestell} \\
 &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Antriebe} \\
 &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Kinematisches System} \\
 &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Steuerungs-/ Mess-/Regel- \& 
 Diagnosesysteme} \\
 &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Hilfssysteme / Peripherie} \\
 \cline{3-4}          
 &       & 
 \multirow{3}[2]{*}{Vorrichtung / Hilfmittel} & 
 \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Vorrichtungs- \& Spannsysteme} \\
 &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Werkstückflusssystem} \\
 &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Steuerung} \\
 \cline{3-4}&       & Werkzeuge &  \\
 \cline{2-4}\\

 %%%
\end{tabularx}%
\label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{longtable}%    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the first solving. The `\longtable` is a way longer, but the issues are the same. I didn't want to copy the entire table for a better overview.

Comment: @Paul but in your real document do you need longtable at all, there really isn't any point to a single column table as there is nothing to align, do you have any row of the longtable with more than one cell?

Comment: I added another row to my example. Their are 6 more rows like this and at the end it is to long for one DIN A4 page. That's why I presumed that I need a longtable for more than one page.

Comment: @Paul no your example is still just a longtable with one row and one column (containing a tabularx) so the outer longtable can do nothing useful at all

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to insert empty rows after the multicolumn?
I had the same problem and I realized it was enough adding empty rows in order to get enough space for the other one.

```
 &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Werkstückflusssystem} \\
    &       &       & \\
    &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Steuerung} \\
    &       &       & \\
```